# search on key up instead of hitting enter

Tags: angular

I have this pipe for search

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(data: any[], search: string): any[] {
    if (data == null){
      return null;
    }

    search = search.toUpperCase();
    return data.filter(x => {
      return (x.firstName.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) !== -1)
...
    });
  }

}
```

and in component.html I have

```
<input #input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="search">

<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let dt of data | searchPipe: input.value"  class="list-group-item">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 clearfix">

      <span>{{ dt.firstName }} {{ dt.lastName }}</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Search works OK but only when I click to **enter** or **backspace** but instead of that I want to search on every key click (for a,b etc.)

How can I do that?

Comment: Bind input box with a property in your component using [NgModel] and use that as a filter instead of input.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind input box with a property in your component using [NgModel] and use that as a filter instead of input.value

In your component, create a property

```
public searchText: string;
```

and use it in like this in your html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Search" id="search">

<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let dt of data | searchPipe: searchText"  class="list-group-item">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 clearfix">

      <span>{{ dt.firstName }} {{ dt.lastName }}</span>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but problem could be with **`#input`** template variable. you could use **`[(ngModel)]`** instead as shown below,

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="myValue" placeholder="Search" id="search">
...
<li *ngFor="let dt of data | searchPipe: myValue"  class="list-group-item">
...
...
```

Now as you type, it should update the result.